# Recommendations on hardware and software

Tags: equipment, gear, sound-design, recommendations, software

Hi

Thanks for another great forum. Really appreciate it!

When delivering sfx for sound fx library companies like Sound-ideas, and Hollywood edge, and not being able to bring the material to a real dubstage, what would you all recomment being used as Converters, eq´s, comps, noise reduction etc. in the mastering process?

Best wishes,

Mikkel

Answer (score 4):

This kind of seems like a solution (spending money) in search of a problem (will it sound good enough?)

I can't speak for those sound effects companies you mentioned, perhaps they have some technical guidelines for submissions.

Once you've conquered the basic problems like preamp hiss and that sort of thing, how does it sound to you? Prosumer gear in the right hands will sound better than top of the line gear used in a sub-optimal manner.

Generally speaking, the price/performance curve is almost logarithmic. Hardware has gotten really good (and affordable) in the last ten years or so. Ask yourself if there is a particular problem that you are trying to solve, and then approach it from that angle. The differences between preamps and converters are possible to hear, but they are far more subtle than you would think if you're just browsing forums where people are often times blowing things way out of proportion. You're going to go into the next order of magnitude on price for a 2% improvement.

Consider renting gear that you're looking at, or see if you can hear a true A/B comparison. Most moderately priced gear available these days sounds pretty excellent.

Answer (score 3):

That is a very open question. To enable people to come up with useful advice, can you give a little more info on:

- your envisioned workflow?
- your budget? (important!)
- your experience with certain tools (knowing how to use the tools you have can be more valuable than having access to 'the best' equipment)

Comment: Thanks alot for helping out. 
Im Using Protools HD and 2x 96 I/O´s, staying in the box.
I was  Uncertain, and curious I guess, if other people stays ITB as well, when delivering material to the sfx companies
Also, I would like to know if a better converter, say the 192, would benefit my end result compared to the 96 I/O, when not bringing my stuff to a (real) pro environment.
Am very aware of the gearslutty-syndrome, and the fact that buying a gazillion plugs and hardware, wont necessarily make my work any better!
Budget: around $3000, I think.

Thanks again.